# Formatting input value

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to format the `<input>` text to fit this format (example): `1050-5562-31AB-ABCD-123E-25DA-1A35-FADC`. I have tried it with `onchange="isHardwareIDValid()"`, `onchange="isHardwareIDValid(hid)"`, `onkeydown="isHardwareIDValid()"`, and `onkeydown="isHardwareIDValid(hid)"` with no luck.

I have an `input`:

```
<input type="text" class="extrainfofield" id="ORDERPARAMETERS" name="ORDERPARAMETERS" value="##$LBL_HARDWAREID##" size="39" placeholder="Enter Hardware ID">
```

I was sent this `javascript` code and haven't been able to get it to work:

```
function isHardwareIDValid (hid) {
    return ((hid.length == 39) && (hid != "0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000") &&
      isStringLimitedToHex (hid.substr (0, 4)) &&(hid.charAt (4) == "-") &&
      isStringLimitedToHex (hid.substr (5, 4)) && (hid.charAt (9) == "-") &&
      isStringLimitedToHex (hid.substr (10, 4)) && (hid.charAt (14) == "-") &&
      isStringLimitedToHex (hid.substr (15, 4)) && (hid.charAt (19) == "-") &&
      isStringLimitedToHex (hid.substr (20, 4)) && (hid.charAt (24) == "-") &&
      isStringLimitedToHex (hid.substr (25, 4)) && (hid.charAt (29) == "-") &&
      isStringLimitedToHex (hid.substr (30, 4)) && (hid.charAt (34) == "-") &&
      isStringLimitedToHex (hid.substr (35, 4)) );
  }
```

I have also used:

```
function isHardwareIDValid () {
    var hid = document.getElementById("ORDERPARAMETERS");
    return ((hid.length == 39) && (hid != "0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0000") &&
      isStringLimitedToHex (hid.substr (0, 4)) && (hid.charAt (4) == "-") &&
      isStringLimitedToHex (hid.substr (5, 4)) && (hid.charAt (9) == "-") &&
      isStringLimitedToHex (hid.substr (10, 4)) && (hid.charAt (14) == "-") &&
      isStringLimitedToHex (hid.substr (15, 4)) && (hid.charAt (19) == "-") &&
      isStringLimitedToHex (hid.substr (20, 4)) && (hid.charAt (24) == "-") &&
      isStringLimitedToHex (hid.substr (25, 4)) && (hid.charAt (29) == "-") &&
      isStringLimitedToHex (hid.substr (30, 4)) && (hid.charAt (34) == "-") &&
      isStringLimitedToHex (hid.substr (35, 4)) );
  }
```

This is inside of a shopping cart, so jQuery might not be an option.

Answer (score 0):

why not use a regex like: https://regex101.com/r/ifuMJP/1

```js
const regex = /^([0-9A-Z]{4}-){7}[0-9A-Z]{4}$/gm;
const str = `1050-5562-31AB-ABCD-123E-25DA-1A35-FADC
1AA0-5562-31AB-ABCD-123E-25DA-1A35-FADC-ACBC
!050-5562-31AB-ABCD-123E-25DA-1A35-FADC
XXXX-XXXX-1234-XXXX-1234-12XX-1234-XXXX`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    console.log(`Found match: ${m[0]}`);
    
}
```

where: `[0-9]{4}-` means 4 digits (from 0-9) numbers followed by a `-`

and : `[0-9A-Z]{4}` means 4 digits (0-9) or charactes (A-Z)

Comment: I was reading about regex, but I just couldn't get it to click with me. I'm not sure if every group of 4 could also contain letters, so would it need to be `[0-9A-Z]{4}` for every group?

Comment: @JeffBerlin exactly! see the updated answer alson containing `^` starts with and `$` ends with

Comment: Can you use regex to format the value as someone is typing it, instead of only matching to see if it's correct?

Comment: depending on what you mean with "format" yes, you can do almost everything

Answer (score 0):

what about using the "pattern" of the input element?

```
<input id="text" type="text" pattern="[0-9A-Z]{4}-[0-9A-Z]{4}- etc"/>
```

you could verify at any time using

```
element.checkValidity() and element.reportValidity() resp.
```

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't too clear and need to edit my question, but I'm looking for a way to add the formatting as they type in the value. Pattern will only show if they didn't type it in that pattern